# Read multiple Arrays from a Cloud Firestore Document in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

### Multiple Arrays in a Firestore Document

I try to read multiple arrays in the same Document (see Database Picture) from Cloud Firestore but for now i can only hardcode the name of the arrays. **How can i display a variable number of arrays?**

I only have to read the data in the document all together.
The Data should be in sync with Firestore so i wrapped everything in a `Streambuilder` and a `Listview.builder` Widget. I tried also some Data deserialization but i don't know if i need this.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,

      //StreamBuilder
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('Variable School Collection')
            .document('Today')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          //check if snapshot has data
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text("Loading..", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title);

            //if snapshot has data:
          } else {
            List<String> names = List.from(snapshot
                .data['1']); //How can I get all arrays in the map?**

            return ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 1,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        names[0], //first element from array
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        names[1], //second element from array
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        names[2], //third element from array
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );  
  }
}
```

**My goal is:** to display all arrays from the firebase Document (today) in my Flutter App.

[Firebase Data Structure with multiple arrays in the Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsOM1.png)

[App preview with only one array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1eUV.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "make this code dynamic"? What needs to be dynamic?  What's your goal here?

Comment: My goal is: to display all arrays from the firebase Document (today) in my Flutter App. See additional images. :)))